# sum of multiple text fields jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code for finding the sum of different textfields and storing that value in another textfield.

```
$(function() {

    $('#input1').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal();
    });

    $('#input2').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal();
    });


    var updateTotal = function () {
        var input1 = parseInt($('#input1').val());
        var input2 = parseInt($('#input2').val());

        if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {

        } else {          
            $('#output1').val(input1 + input2);
        }
    };

    var output_total = $('#output');

});
```

This code adds value of input1 + input2 to output1.
TextFields are aligned as:
input1 input2 output1 input3 input4 output2 output.
Similar code is used to add value of input3 + input4() to output2. When i use the code for adding both outputs generated output1+output2 to output, it doesn't work. What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please (including your HTML)? Also, a jsFiddle.net example might be helpful.

Comment: Shouldn't `$(function () {` be `(function () {`? Or does it matter? Can you also explain what doesn't work? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Huangism - no, that's correct. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @j08691 works without the $ as well doesn't it?

Comment: if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {}..... really?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me , may be this code will be helpful for you

```
$(function () {
    $('#input1,#input2').keyup(function () {
        var input1 = parseInt($('#input1').val(),10);
        var input2 = parseInt($('#input2').val(),10);
        if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {} else {
            $('#output1').val(input1 + input2);
            update();
        }
    });
    $('#input3,#input4').keyup(function () {
        var input3 = parseInt($('#input3').val(),10);
        var input4 = parseInt($('#input4').val(),10);
        if (isNaN(input3) || isNaN(input4)) {} else {
            $('#output2').val(input3 + input4);
            update();
        }
    });
    function update(){
        $('#output').val(parseInt($('#output2').val(),10)+parseInt($('#output1').val(),10));
    }
});
```